# How to find all Keys in a hash have a value in Perl

Tags: perl

How do you determine if all hash keys have some value ?

Comment: what does it mean "have some value"? if there is a key, there is a value. the value might be undef, but it's still a value. what do you want to check for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `perldoc -f exists`:

```
               print "Exists\n"    if exists $hash{$key};
               print "Defined\n"   if defined $hash{$key};
               print "True\n"      if $hash{$key};

               print "Exists\n"    if exists $array[$index];
               print "Defined\n"   if defined $array[$index];
               print "True\n"      if $array[$index];
```

> A hash or array element can be true
>   only if it's defined, and defined if
>   it exists, but the reverse doesn't
>   necessarily hold true.

Comment: exists and delete on array elements have interesting and not always useful properties.  If you really need those, you're best off using a hash.

Answer (score 7):

Feed the result of [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) into [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) with [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html)

```
my @keys_with_values = grep { defined $hash{$_} } keys %hash;
```

Rereading your question, it seems like you are trying to find out if any of the values in your hash are undefined, in which case you could say something like

```
my @keys_without_values = grep { not defined $hash{$_} }, keys %hash;
if (@keys_without_values) {
    print "the following keys do not have a value: ",
        join(", ", @keys_without_values), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the key exists, it has a value (even if that value is `undef`) so:

```
my @keys_with_values = keys %some_hash;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete thus this code can be answer ;-)

```
my %hash = (
    a => 'any value',
    b => 'some value',
    c => 'other value',
    d => 'some value'
);
my @keys_with_some_value = grep $hash{$_} eq 'some value', keys %hash;
```

**EDIT:** I had reread question again and decided that answer can be:

```
sub all (&@) {
  my $pred = shift();
  $pred->() or return for @_;
  return 1;
}

my $all_keys_has_some_value = all {$_ eq 'some value'} values %hash;
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to know if all values are defined, or any undefined this will do that:

```
sub all_defined{
  my( $hash ) = @_;
  for my $value ( values %$hash ){
    return '' unless defined $value; # false but defined
  }
  return 1; #true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more way, using [each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html). TIMTOWDI

```
 while (my($key, $value) = each(%hash)) {
      say "$key has no value!" if ( not defined $value);
 }
```